# Is interest income added to EBIT to calculate EBT?

Tags: accounting, financial, profit

I am preparing a financing model and in the template the EBT calculation is:
*EBT=EBIT - Interest Expense*.

However, I wonder if interest income (from keeping the money on the bank) should be added, i.e. *EBT=EBIT + Interest Income - Interest Expense*?

Many thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think interest income should have already been included in EBIT as non operating income.  You might want to check that before you add it.

Comment: Yes, EBIT already includes all kinds of ways the company has made money... All that is left to do is to pay the Lenders ( => EBT) and the Tax Man, and the rest is our earnings (=>E).